# Creating an equation that will return a linear result

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculator

I am a web developer and I need to create a multiplier between 1 & 10 or as close as possible. I have a variable value that is essentially a date range in days (1 day ago = 1, 10 days ago is 10... 1000 days ago is 1000). I need to create an equation that will convert this date range into a suitable multiplier for my sorting algorithm, decimals allowed. My best attempts so far:

```
1 + (365 / $diffdays);
1 + (365 / 1) = 366;
1 + (365 / 10) = 37.5;
1 + (365 / 100) = 4.65;
1 + (365 / 365) = 2;

1 + (10 / $diffdays);
1 + (10 / 1) = 11;
1 + (10 / 10) = 2;
1 + (10 / 100) = 1.1;
1 + (10 / 365) = 1.027; 

1 + (1 / $diffdays);
1 + (1 / 1) = 2;
1 + (1 / 10) = 1.1;
1 + (1 / 100) = 1.01;
1 + (1 / 365) = 1.0027;
```

The first provides too large or a multiplier at the top end. The other is not large enough.

The middle equation is pretty close however it is an exponential curve that is created, **is there a way to convert it into a linear result by modifying the equation?**

**Please can someone apply their wizardry to help create an equation that is in between the two attempts provided?**

**EDIT:**

I plan to use the multiplier within my relevance calculator for articles, in which if the title of the article matches it will receive a boost, if the words in the content of an article it receives a boost but less so than the title hits.

I then need to provide a boost based on when the article was posted. However, an exponential curve is providing too large of a gap between dates. It very quickly goes from being a 100 x multiplier down to 1.027 multiplier which is not fair.

The code that applies this to the articles weight is:

```
$sameDay = 10;
$dateMatch = $diffDaysAsPercentage * $sameDay;
$weight *= $dateMatch;
```

Where $diffDaysAsPercentage is the result of the equation we are working on.

**EDIT 2:**
It might also be worth mentioning that articles can date back further than 365 days, they can be multiple years old too (e.g 1000 days = 1000).

**EDIT 3:**
Using log seems like the right way to solve the problem, there does seem to be a value quickly similar problem, the answer quickly slips into the 0.x values. * attached image *

[image: Examples of log()]

Comment: You need to make clear what you want your "multiplier" to do. Give some examples on smaller ranges and explain how the "multiplier" helps in sorting.

Comment: On it... Give me two minutes :)

Comment: @coffeemath - feel free to request more information, appreciate the help getting my post to be understandable, its very awkward to try explain without going full nerdy code chatter.

Comment: Does it need to provide a unique result for each and every $diffdays or can there be repeats regardless of this value?

Comment: @moo - Same date can equal the same value, it will then receive the other boosts that provide more precedence, it is rare to receive an exactly identical multiplier from the other factors that come before the multiplier we are equating now.

Comment: @Moo - please elaborate, I appreciate the answer may be right in front of me :)

Comment: @Moo - The answer is right in front of me but I am maths blind. I need some 200iq influence!

Comment: @Moo - I think you're onto something though, somehow plugging in what is discussed in the article linked would be along the right lines

Comment: @Moo - I am thinking maybe this won't work as we only have one value to work with, not all of them at the same time. This modifier is applied inside a loop, each loop is a single article.

Comment: @Moo - Thanks for the clarification, may I request more information, potentially an example of how it can be applied individually to the snippets of calculations above?

Comment: @Moo - I can see this being very powerful, I have expanded my question to return the result, are you able to explain how the log() is actually running to return the result maybe use what appears at first glance the simplest of calucations possible with the log() function, log(1000000000) is returning 10. Is it getting the root ^ 10?

Comment: @Moo - Decimals are accepted :) Appreciate the link though. I am just wondering if there is a calculation that can be placed within the log() that would help spread out the answers between 1 - 10000, to cover the full range of 1 - 10?